# SQL Or Statement with multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm fairly new to SQL Server and I have a query that isn't recognizing part of the WHERE statement. My suspicion is that the OR is pulling from multiple tables (X and Y). I tried looking for an answer and didn't find anything. Can anyone confirm this?

```
SELECT 
   X.ID,
   X.FN,
   X.LN,
   X.SC,
   Y.ER,
   CONVERT(VARCHAR,Y.LD,101)    

FROM X JOIN Y ON X.ID = Y.ID 

WHERE  (Y.ER <> 240 OR X.EOY <> 240)
   AND Y.YR = 2016
   AND X.SP LIKE 'T'
```

Comment: What do you mean by it isn't recognising the `WHERE`? I can't see anything wrong with it. On the other hand, you're referencing a object/alias, `y`, however, that isn't declared in your SQL. You have an object called `X` and an object called `ENR`.

Comment: You are not declaring any Y in your query. The join has 'ENR' table, not Y.

Comment: Sorry guys. I was changing the table names in my query and I missed the one. I have edited it now

Comment: So, @amwakatsuki, what do you mean by "isn't recognising part of the `WHERE`"?

Comment: What you need in the return? What is your rule? Can you share some sample data?

Comment: The results from the query look to be completely ignoring (Y.ER <> 240 OR X.EOY <> 240) from the WHERE

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `X.SP LIKE 'T'`? This is the same as `X.SP = 'T'`. Should that cluase have a wildcard, perhaps?

Comment: But what is the rule? To this (Y.ER <> 240 OR X.EOY <> 240) work this part needs to be true also: AND Y.YR = 2016  AND X.SP LIKE 'T'

Comment: @RogérioCarvalhoBatista due to confidentiality I can't share the results but let me work on changing the confidential stuff

Comment: Just create some sample data, it doesn't need to be the original, only a fake data to illustrate.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Y as a table alias, however, it has never been defined.

```
SELECT 
   X.ID,
   X.FN,
   X.LN,
   X.SC,
   Y.ER,
   CONVERT(VARCHAR,Y.LD,101)    

FROM X JOIN ENR Y ON X.ID = Y.ID 

WHERE  (Y.ER <> 240 OR X.EOY <> 240)
   AND Y.YR = 2016
   AND X.SP LIKE 'T'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not defining Y in the from clause. It looks like ENR is the second table. You need to say “ENR as Y” or just “ENR Y” for the letter Y to represent this table.

Answer (score 0):

You need a % in your like clause to indicate what type of substring.

```
SELECT 
   X.ID,
   X.FN,
   X.LN,
   X.SC,
   Y.ER,
   CONVERT(VARCHAR,Y.LD,101)    

FROM X JOIN ENR ON X.ID = Y.ID 

WHERE  (Y.ER <> 240 OR X.EOY <> 240)
   AND Y.YR = 2016
   AND X.SP LIKE 'T%'
```

This would be any X.SP that starts with T.

```
  SELECT 
       X.ID,
       X.FN,
       X.LN,
       X.SC,
       Y.ER,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR,Y.LD,101)    

    FROM X JOIN ENR ON X.ID = Y.ID 

    WHERE  (Y.ER <> 240 OR X.EOY <> 240)
       AND Y.YR = 2016
       AND X.SP LIKE '%T%'
```

Mean any X.SP containing T.

If this does not solve the problem please provide more information on the problem such as you are seeing some records or you are seeing no records.

Answer (score -2):

So I accidentally came across the answer in making some fake data. It turns out I needed to add X.EOY in the SELECT for it to be recognized in the WHERE.

```
SELECT 
  X.ID,
  X.FN,
  X.LN,
  X.SC,
  X.EOY,
  Y.ER,
  CONVERT(VARCHAR,Y.LD,101)    

FROM X JOIN Y ON X.ID = Y.ID 

WHERE  (Y.ER <> 240 OR X.EOY <> 240)
  AND Y.YR = 2016
  AND X.SP LIKE 'T'
```

Comment: That makes **ZERO** sense. `Where` conditions are applied no matter you select the filtered column or not

Comment: Seconding what @Pரதீப் said.  This answer makes no sense

Comment: I'm with you guys on this as well, but that's what worked for me. With my limited experience, I have noticed the same as mentioned by @Pரதீப் so I had expected my original query to work as well. If it makes any difference, I'm working with Microsoft SQL Server Mananagement Studio v. 14.0.17213.